# How do I keep my Elastic Beanstalk instance healthy when using Spring WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter?

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

**Context**

I'm hosting a Java SpringBoot application on Elastic Beanstalk, and it's running. I've just merged a branch that adds WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, requiring a username and password on loading the page.

When run locally, the environment properties are in `application.properties`, and they are set in Travis and on Elastic Beanstalk under Configuration -> Software.

When I `Go to Environment`, an alert prompts me for username and password, after which it works.

Setting incorrect username or password in Configuration causes `502` errors, as expected.

**Problem**

The health of this instance is 'Severe', with `100.0 % of the requests are erroring with HTTP 4xx.`

I believe that I've found the relevant error in the logs:

`ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: username cannot be null`

**New file, SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser(environment.getProperty("USERNAME")).password("{noop}" + environment.getProperty("PASSWORD")).roles("USER");
    }
}
```

My understanding of this is that the Health of the instance is evaluated by loading `/`, at which point no username is found so the page fails to load.

If this is the case, how can I allow the Health checks to not fail because of http security?

Answer (score 0):

**Spring has an 'Actuator' for opening up a Health Check endpoint**

By adding the gradle dependency `compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator'`, the application gains an `/actuator/health` endpoint that the ELB Load Balancer can be configured to perform checks on instead of `/`.